# Класс Robot в Java: IllegalArgumentException: Invalid key code

Tags: java

Здравствуйте, в `Java` присутствует класс `Robot`, который симулирует нажатия пользователем кнопок на клавиатуре и мышке.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему у меня здесь при попытке нажатия **запятой** выбрасывает `IllegalArgumentException: Invalid key code`

```
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_COMMA);
        robot.delay(20);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_COMMA);
```

А если клавиша другая, например **буква**, то все работает:

```
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_D);
        robot.delay(20);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_D);
```

Comment: Логи можно посмотреть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому-что класс Робот имитирует нажатие одной кнопки,а запятая, это shift + "."
как-то так...

Comment: На английской раскладке есть клавиша запятой....

Comment: эм...вопрос не в наличии клавиши с запятой, а коде клавиши. попробуйте сначала сделать
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
потом ввести Вашу кнопку
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);